# unable to do add/edit on same view and controller in mvc

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

As I was trying to create and edit using single view and on the same controller,the error was coming while managing ID.
I was able to manage it while EDITING by :

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
```

but while creating(ADDING) a record I was not able to get ID
[ **ERROR** : The **ID** field is required ]
.The error came while checking (**ID is a Primary Key** in DB):

```
ModelState.IsValid
```

as I was able to manage ID by using :

```
  [Bind(Exclude = "ID")]
```

but again this will create an issue while editing.SO please give me a way to add and edit using same controller.

Comment: You should set the ID as null when creating, before saving the information using EntityFramework. You should have giving us more information like the View + Controller + Model information.

Answer (score 0):

Try set Id=0 when adding and you need hidden input for Id for editing (to send back Id).

When you creating new object and you set Id=0 it's mean that EF will compute Id itself.

When you editing object you must send back Id to controller as Id is properties of your object and it's used by EF to determine which object is updating.

Excluding Id from binding it's not good idea ;) If you exclude Id so how controller/EF will know which object was sent back from view?

**Clarification:**

In your view you should have just: `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)`

In your case you can/should set `Id=0` in controller/action when you adding new object.

If you want add/edit object in one view, you can create empty object (and set Id=0) in your add action and pass it trough to your view... Then you always have valid object/Model in your view whatever you adding or editing.

Example of add action:

```
public void Create(int id)
{
    // ...

    return View(new YourObject {
        Id = 0,
    });
}
```

Comment: ok, now by setting the default value of hidden field as 0 **@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID, new { Value = "0" })** my code runs fine

Comment: but again the issue is coming while editing the value of ID is still 0

Comment: Ok, It should be just `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)` in your view, but value `Id=0` you should/can set in controller/action when you adding new object. If you want add/edit object in one view, you can create empty object (and set Id=0) in your add action and pass it trough to your view... Then you always have valid object/Model in your view.

Comment: Maybe give me example of your controller and view code, and I will show you how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You always include id as a hidden field on your view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
```

Do not make the Id property required so the validation will always pass. If it is 0 or null (if your Id property is of nullable type) then you treat it as an insert. Otherwise perform an update:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if (!model.Id.HasValue || model.Id == 0){
    {
       // Do insert here..
    } else {
       // Do update here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Actualy the ID is a primary key,so this will be an issue while checking **modelstate.isvalid**

Comment: @Avin Is your primary key nullable or not? If it's not then it will be a 0 so it will satisfy the required attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a Single view for create and Edit then you should first check for the ID

If a form passes the id as 0 then its Create otherwise Edit

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Model model)
{
     if(model.id != 0 )
      {
        //Edit Code here
      }
     if( model.id == 0)
      {
       //Create Code Here
      }
return RedirectToAction("","");
}
```

As you have already maintained the ID as hidden. You wont have any problem on passing the ID.

But Before HTTPPOST

On HTTPGET... Follow Following Code

```
Public Action Result Create(int id = 0)
{
    if(id != 0)
    {
      var model = //code for selecting the data for the respective id
      return view (model);
    }
    return view();
}
```

EDITED : This should work out...

Comment: yeah but you are not checking **ModelState**,the issue is on model state,the ID while Adding is Null and it cant be null as its a **Primary Key**